# Валидация данных при отправке Axios во Vue компоненте

Tags: javascript, vue.js, requests, валидация, axios

подскажите пожалуйста у меня есть метод отправки формы данных через axios:

```
sendForm() {
      if (false) {
        const claimNumId = window.location.search.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
        axios({
          method: "post",
          url: "/ajax/qsnnr/save/",
          data: {
          "claimNum": claimNumId,
          "questions": [
            {
              "name": '121',
              "value": this.inputValues.questionValue1
            },
            {
              "name": '122',
              "value": this.inputValues.questionValue2
            },
            {
              "name": '123',
              "value": this.inputValues.questionValue3
            },
            {
              "name": '124',
              "value": this.inputValues.comment
            },
            {
              "name": '125',
              "value": this.inputValues.comment2
            }
          ],
            status: 1,
          },
          headers: {"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"},
        })
            .then(function (response) {
              console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (response) {
              console.log(response);
            });
      } else {

      //  тут реализовать проверку 

      }
    },
```

Задача заключается в том, что бы если одно из значений value является пустым, то запретить отправку формы.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что мешает в блоке `if (false) {` сделать нужную проверку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const questions = [
            {
              "name": '121',
              "value": this.inputValues.questionValue1
            },
            {
              "name": '122',
              "value": this.inputValues.questionValue2
            },
            {
              "name": '123',
              "value": this.inputValues.questionValue3
            },
            {
              "name": '124',
              "value": this.inputValues.comment
            },
            {
              "name": '125',
              "value": this.inputValues.comment2
            }
          ];
...   
if (!questions.some(el => el.value === '')) {
//отправляем запрос
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось)